# Declarando variable .value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

soy nuevo con javascript y se me había ocurrido hacer un programa para sacar el porcentaje entre dos números.

Me estaba rompiendo la cabeza para saber porque no funcionaba y este era el código que tenia:

```
/*Javascript*/
/*Declarar variables*/

var numero1 = document.getElementById('primer-numero').value;
var numero2 = document.getElementById('segundo-numero').value;
var btnCalcular = document.getElementById('calcular');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

btnCalcular.addEventListener("click", () => {

    /*OPERACION PORCENTAJE*/

    function operacion(numero1, numero2) {
        
        let porcentaje = (parseInt(numero1) / parseInt(numero2)) * 100;

        return porcentaje;

    }
    /*MOSTRAR RESULTADO*/

    function result(operacion) {
        resultado.value = operacion + "%";
    }

    result(operacion(numero1, numero2));

});
```

Y luego de intentarlo lo pude hacer funcionar sacandole el método .value a las dos primeras variables y asignándoselas después dentro de la función operación:

```
/*Declarar variables*/

var numero1 = document.getElementById('primer-numero');
var numero2 = document.getElementById('segundo-numero');
var btnCalcular = document.getElementById('calcular');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

btnCalcular.addEventListener("click", () => {

    /*OPERACION PORCENTAJE*/

    function operacion(numero1, numero2) {
        
        let porcentaje = (parseInt(numero1.value) / parseInt(numero2.value)) * 100;

        return porcentaje;

    }
    /*MOSTRAR RESULTADO*/

    function result(operacion) {
        resultado.value = operacion + "%";
    }

    result(operacion(numero1, numero2));

});
```

Porque de la primera forma no funciona y la otra si?
Es simplemente para saber como funciona mejor el lenguaje y entender un poco mas.
Gracias espero que se haya entendido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu primer ejemplo

```
var numero1 = document.getElementById('primer-numero').value;
var numero2 = document.getElementById('segundo-numero').value;
```

estás declarando numero1 y numero2 con el valor que tienen primer-numero y segundo-numero en el momento de declarar las variables. Osea aún están vacíos.

en tu segundo ejemplo lo estás haciendo adentro del

```
btnCalcular.addEventListener("click", () => {});
```

Osea, detecta el click y luego se fija los .value de primer-numero y segundo-numero.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada! Si contesto tu pregunta, no te olvides de marcarla como respuesta aceptada y darle un voto positivo.